# extending an object's parameter Javascript (Coffeescript code)

Tags: javascript, object, coffeescript

I have this code:

```
tickets = new Object()
$(this).parents('.request-form').find('.Single').each ->
    if $(this).find('.checkBoxParent input').prop('checked')
        params = new Object()
        params.sarId = $(this).parents('.request-form').find('.sarId').text()
        params.comments = $(this).find('.commentBoxParent textarea').val()
        params.serviceId = $(this).find('.serviceId').text()
        tickets[$(this).parents('.categoryQuestions').find('.form-label').text()] = params
```

The idea is that tickets will stay empty, but as it looks through the html, it will add items and a list of sub items to it.

for example, it can find a label "classrooms" and the 3 parameters for that part of the form.

Thus I want the object to look like:

`tickets[classrooms][{sarId: 1, serviceId: 3, comments: "hi"}]`

Then it can find another "classroom" label and I want it to append, such that the object will now look like:

`tickets[classrooms][{sarId: 1, serviceId: 3, comments: "hi"}, {sarId: 1, serviceId: 6, comments: "Another comment"}]`

How can I make this happen?

Comment: You cannot use objects as property keys. What do you really want?

Answer (score 0):

switching it to a multidimensional array/object worked like this:

```
    requestForm = $(this).parents('.request-form');
    tickets = {}
    requestForm.find('.Single').each ->
        #alert("this should happen... 4 times")
        focus = $(this)
        if $(this).find('.checkBoxParent input').prop('checked')
            label = $(this).parents('.categoryQuestions').find('.form-label').text()
            if (!tickets.hasOwnProperty(label))
                tickets[label] = []
            tickets[label].push({
                sarId: requestForm.find('.sarId').text(),
                comments: $(this).find('.commentBoxParent textarea').val(),
                serviceId: $(this).find('.serviceId').text()
                })
```